Mesh triangle colors being lost on rendering in Rhino7
I am working on a project using Rhino7. I need to color each triangle of a triangle mesh with a different color. I have managed to do so using Rhino Python Scripting, but only on the visualizer: once I try to render the scene, I lose the colors on the mesh. Find attached an image of the visualizer and the rendering respectively. You can also find the ply file and the csv with the color data here. You will find the code I use for generating the image that appears on the visualizer here too.
I have tried adding a texture to the mesh but it's not working (or I am doing it wrongly).
Any suggestions?
Yours,


import rhinoscriptsyntax as rs
import scriptcontext as sc
import Rhino
import csv
import System.Drawing.Color

def assign_colors_to_mesh_faces():
    # Prompt the user to select a mesh
    mesh_id = rs.GetObject("Select the mesh to color", rs.filter.mesh)
    if not mesh_id:
        print("No mesh selected.")
        return

    # Get the mesh geometry
    mesh = rs.coercemesh(mesh_id)
    if not mesh:
        print("Failed to get mesh geometry.")
        return

    face_count = mesh.Faces.Count

    # Prompt the user to select a CSV file
    csv_file = rs.OpenFileName("Select CSV file with RGB values", "*.csv")
    if not csv_file:
        print("No CSV file selected.")
        return

    # Read RGB values from the CSV file
    rgb_list = []
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if len(row) >= 3:
                try:
                    r = int(row[0])
                    g = int(row[1])
                    b = int(row[2])
                    rgb_list.append(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))
                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid RGB values: {}".format(row))
                    return
            else:
                print("Incomplete RGB values: {}".format(row))
                return

    if len(rgb_list) != face_count:
        print("Mismatch between number of RGB values and mesh faces.")
        print("Mesh faces: {}, RGB values: {}".format(face_count, len(rgb_list)))
        return

    # Initialize vertex colors
    mesh.VertexColors.CreateMonotoneMesh(System.Drawing.Color.White)

    # Assign colors to mesh faces
    for i in range(face_count):
        color = rgb_list[i]
        face = mesh.Faces[i]

        # Get vertex indices of the face
        vi = [face.A, face.B, face.C]
        if face.IsQuad:
            vi.append(face.D)

        # Assign color to vertices of the face
        for idx in vi:
            mesh.VertexColors[idx] = color

    # Replace the mesh in the document
    sc.doc.Objects.Replace(mesh_id, mesh)
    sc.doc.Views.Redraw()

    print("Colors assigned successfully.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    assign_colors_to_mesh_faces()


